# How can I get the Unity interface to work on my netbook?

Tags: unity, 10.10, ubuntu-netbook

I have 10.10 installed on my netbook, but the Unity interface that came with it does not seem to work. The top and side bar are missing and several graphical menus don't work. I have tried updating my graphics card but have had no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If you can't get unity to work on your netbook, try to install package "ubuntu-desktop" (`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`) and login to Ubuntu Desktop instead of Ubuntu Netbook. But If you really want a unity interface you have to wait for Ubuntu 11.04 to be released, because Unity in Ubuntu 10.10 use mutter which doesn't support a lot of graphic cards.

Comment: You might also want to try the 2D Unity, which is available in a PPA while it's in development for 11.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can also select a different interface, at the login time. If your netbook automatically logs you in, simply log out from the main menu. Once on the login window, select a different interface from one of the buttons on the bottom. That's how I got back to the classic display using the ubuntu Netbook remix instead of the new interface. My main reason for this change, in my case, was a very sluggish display performance, where every click took about 5 seconds before seeing any actual feedback on the display. I know there was a fix for it, somewher, but I did not like the interface anyway.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help.  I was able to switch it to the desktop interface. I figured there would be some initial issues with how old my laptop is, but other than the unity interface not working it seems to run pretty well.